# How to set a time delay on dropping draggable element

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

Allow drop of element after 5 seconds from the previous drop attempt and output message if it is still under 5 seconds?

```
grid.droppable({
    accept: '.draggable-item',
    tolerance: 'pointer',
    drop: function() {
        setTimeout(function() {
            // 
        }, 5000);
    }
});
```

Comment: So you want to prevent someone from dropping an element for 5 seconds after an item was dropped?

Comment: @Twisty, yup I just want to prevent the user from dropping draggable in a fast sequence. I need to create some time for the widget to be fully loaded as it has some graphical data need to be displayed through ajax call

Comment: You may want to consider disabling the droppable and they when the item is `.ready()` droppable can be enabled.